# Brewing beer from tropical ingredients

Tags: beer

What's the best reading material for a starter who would like to brew good tasting beer from tropical ingredients?

Comment: Can you define tropical ingredients?  Do you mean tropical fruit or something else?  You might be better off listing exactly what you want to brew with as sometimes people have specific recommendations based on the grain/fruit/adjunct/hop in question.

Answer (score 3):

"Experimental Homebrew" by Denny Conn and Drew Beechum

(Denny I'll provide my webmoney# shortly, so you could transfer the commissions :) )

Answer (score 1):

The usual answer to this question is the book "Designing Great Beers" by Ray Daniels.

But this is not a beginners' book on brewing.
For new brewing advice, "How to Brew" by John Palmer is very good.

My answer, assuming you mean brewing with tropical fruit: make a beer, then in the last stage of fermentation (after 1 week say) add chopped fruit into the fermenter.  This is a somewhat safer time, since the beer is already low-oxygen, and low-pH. This helps protect it from infection from micro-organisms on the fruit.

Any since "tropical" typically indicates a high ambient temperature - don't brew beer unless you can keep the temperature under 20C (around 18C is better).  Beer fermented at ambient summer temperatures in the tropics is difficult to get a pleasing result.